# How can I change URL symbols?

Tags: url, seo

I want to use Georgian characters in my URL (e.g "https://www.example.ge/post/ქართული-სიმბოლოები") and my result in a browser is correct but in SEO audit look as "https://www.example.ge/post/ááá¢ááááááªáá

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). There are quite a few tools on the **[web](https://www.google.com/search?q=encoding%20url%20online)**. E.g., on [one of these tools](https://www.urlencoder.org/) your url is encoded like this:

https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.ge%2Fpost%2F%E1%83%A5%E1%83%90%E1%83%A0%E1%83%97%E1%83%A3%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98-%E1%83%A1%E1%83%98%E1%83%9B%E1%83%91%E1%83%9D%E1%83%9A%E1%83%9D%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%98

In the address bar this will be shown as your Georgian characters.